# Where location log file httpd server

Tags: apache, web, server, httpd.conf, virtual-hosts

Please help, I am actually not a server admin, I just want to know, my server has some virtualhost, for example:

```
ServerAdmin arif@dummy-host.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/testing/
ServerName cg.blender.com
ErrorLog logs/cg.blender-error_log
CustomLog logs/cg.blender-access_log common
```

So where is the actual access log file location,
/var/www/testing/logs/.. or /var/logs/...

Sorry I am less understood,

Comment: Apache logs will be in /var/log/apache2/

Answer (score 1):

You can find the log in the following path

```
/var/log/http/
```

For httpd server

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration file, when paths are relative, they are relative to "**ServerRoot**" path.

See the documentation:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serverroot